# Displaying CR part of YCR_CB python opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am trying to generate a colour space such that the red sections of a set of images are easily seen by converting it from BGR to YCR_CB using python and opencv like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory_to_cycle, filename),  cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
width, height = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
img_yCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

cv2.imshow('image', img_yCrCb[:,:,1])
```

but I am getting this error caused by cv2.imshow('image', img_yCrCb[:,:,1])

```
error:  C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type
```

and I don't understand why since others that have used this exact code have it working

Does anyone have any ideas whether its to fix this problem or an alternative solution to what I am trying to do?

Comment: No, it's working fine on my machine .

Comment: Turns out I needed to update my opencv and numpy version so it now works